# Error "incompatible types in assignment", and I don't know why

Tags: c

When I compile this code I get this error:

> Q3.c:15: error: incompatible types in assignment

Some knows why?

The purpose of the code is to get 10 names and print them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME 10
#define LONG 50

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char names[NAME][LONG] = {0};
    printf("Enter 10 names:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < NAME; i++)
    {
        fgets(names[i], LONG, stdin);
        names[strcspn(names[i], "\n")] = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < NAME; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", names[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        names[strcspn(names[i], "\n")] = 0;
```

is wrong because `names[something]` is an array (`char[LONG]`) and you cannot assign things there.

It seems the line should be

```
        names[i][strcspn(names[i], "\n")] = 0;
```